# User.getcurrentUser return null

Tags: android, parse-platform

We are using Parse Android SDK 1.10.1
We have enabled local storage (we have pinned the User object also)

We are able to signup the new user and they are getting logged in also in offline after relaunch.

But some times, We are getting User.getCurrentUser = null

how we find that ??

Because we have put one condition that

```
if(User.getCurrentUser != null) {
    //Screen A
}
```

Some time We are not landing to Screen A and stays on Old Screen

Answer (score 1):

Use `ParseUser` instead `User`

```
ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
```

Comment: User extends ParseUser.

Comment: It is same class. but some time returns null even local storage enable